# Spark Error org.apache.spark.SparkException: Error communicating with MapOutputTracker during Spark submit

Tags: elasticsearch, spark-submit, spark-java

Getting below exception

```
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Error communicating with MapOutputTracker
    at org.apache.spark.MapOutputTracker.askTracker(MapOutputTracker.scala:523)
    at org.apache.spark.MapOutputTrackerWorker.$anonfun$getStatuses$7(MapOutputTracker.scala:1424)
    at org.apache.spark.util.KeyLock.withLock(KeyLock.scala:64)
    at org.apache.spark.MapOutputTrackerWorker.getStatuses(MapOutputTracker.scala:1420)
    at org.apache.spark.MapOutputTrackerWorker.getMapSizesByExecutorIdImpl(MapOutputTracker.scala:1286)
    at org.apache.spark.MapOutputTrackerWorker.getMapSizesByExecutorId(MapOutputTracker.scala:1256)
    at org.apache.spark.shuffle.sort.SortShuffleManager.getReader(SortShuffleManager.scala:140)
    at org.apache.spark.shuffle.ShuffleManager.getReader(ShuffleManager.scala:63)
    at org.apache.spark.shuffle.ShuffleManager.getReader$(ShuffleManager.scala:57)
    at org.apache.spark.shuffle.sort.SortShuffleManager.getReader(SortShuffleManager.scala:73)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.ShuffledRDD.compute(ShuffledRDD.scala:106)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:365)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:329)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:365)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:329)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:136)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$3(Executor.scala:548)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1504)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:551)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
Caused by: org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeoutException: Futures timed out after [10 seconds]. This timeout is controlled by spark.rpc.askTimeout
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeout.org$apache$spark$rpc$RpcTimeout$$createRpcTimeoutException(RpcTimeout.scala:47)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeout$$anonfun$addMessageIfTimeout$1.applyOrElse(RpcTimeout.scala:62)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeout$$anonfun$addMessageIfTimeout$1.applyOrElse(RpcTimeout.scala:58)
    at scala.runtime.AbstractPartialFunction.apply(AbstractPartialFunction.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeout.awaitResult(RpcTimeout.scala:76)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcEndpointRef.askSync(RpcEndpointRef.scala:103)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcEndpointRef.askSync(RpcEndpointRef.scala:87)
    at org.apache.spark.MapOutputTracker.askTracker(MapOutputTracker.scala:519)
    ... 23 more
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Futures timed out after [10 seconds]
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.ready(Promise.scala:259)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.result(Promise.scala:263)
    at org.apache.spark.util.ThreadUtils$.awaitResult(ThreadUtils.scala:293)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeout.awaitResult(RpcTimeout.scala:75)
```

I tried to updgrade the spark cluster from 2.4.4 to spark version 3.3.2. So I have to recompile the spark jar and its dependencies to support scala 2.12 version, as the spark 3+ version only supports scala 2.12 version.

I am using Elasticsearch-spark to read and update the index in ELK. So upgrade it to below version

```
  <dependency>
            <groupId>org.elasticsearch</groupId>
            <artifactId>elasticsearch-spark-30_2.12</artifactId>
            <version>7.16.3</version>
        </dependency>
 <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-core_2.12</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.2</version>
        </dependency>
```

So when I sumbit the app , I am getting the exception

The app is working fine in Staging, and the same 2.4.4 JAR was working in Spark 2.4.4 for even higher load in PROD till date without any issue, so Looks like I am missing some configuration which is causing this issue . Can some one help me on this as I am struggling to resolve it for past couple of days. And FYI, I am a new to JAVA.